# Base64 encoded string is not finding route if reload in blazor when it is long

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, blazor

In my blazor server project, I have a page where I send some data to another page in the url as base64 encoded string.
The page component has page attribute like below

```
@page "/PurchaseOrderTemplateViewer/{ReportParameters}"
```

when I navigate to this page from another page like this

```
var reportModel = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(State.Model);
var reportParameters = Base64UrlEncoder.Encode(reportModel);
NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/PurchaseOrderTemplateViewer/" + reportParameters);
```

it finds the route and renders the page.
But if I reload the page or open the page in a new tab using JS Runtime like below

```
await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("open", "/PurchaseOrderTemplateViewer/" + reportParameters, "_blank");
```

it doesn't find the route and says invalid url.

Here is the exact url: https://localhost: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

**Note: I validated that this is a valid base64 encoded string and it has a total of 736 characters.
If I shorten the encoded part, and open the url in a new tab, then it finds the route.**

I have no answer why it is behaving like this.